# Tingling in tricep muscles when working out

Tags: weightlifting, workout, gym, injury

Whenever I work out chest and triceps, or any push exercise really, I get a tingling in my tricep area on my arm. It didn’t hurt however I stop my set whenever I feel it. It only started happening when I moved up to 60 pound dumbbells but even when I moved back down it continues to happen which is why I worry that I damaged something.

A quick google search told me I had an entrapped nerve and that I should rest for a week and do stretches which I did, however it still happens so I’m wondering what course of action I should take to hopefully fix the problem for good.

Comment: See a doctor if you're worried. We cannot provide medical advice / a diagnosis.